# Can we create rectangular ring?

Tags: java, android, shapes

From what I learn, there are 4 shapes that available for "android:shape" which are rectangular, line, oval and ring. I want to create a rectangular ring and it seems that, 'android:shape="ring"' only support circle shape ring, not rectangular shape ring. how can I create the rectangular ring with a hole/transparent in the middle of it?

Comment: I don't understand what a *rectangular ring* looks like / means.. Can you show us how it should look?

Comment: I guess OP means something like a border.

Comment: I believe the OP is referring to a "rounded rectangle".

Comment: Yes, we can, USe a rectange. Give it a **stroke** color and width, no fill (or transparent fill). That's a frame (or "rectangular ring").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ring.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
             <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

             <stroke android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                     android:width="20dp"/>   

             <size android:height="200dp"
                   android:width="200dp"/>  //same height and width gives you a square

       </shape>
```

[image]

This will give you a shape like this if that is what you want

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a rectangle with rounded corners, use the `rectangle` shape with `corners` element.

**Updated with a hole in the middle**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke 
        android:color="@android:color/black" 
        android:width="5dp"/>
    <size
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="30dp" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what was asked for.